# Who Am I? Born in NYC

Tags: rebus

[image]

Who am I?

**Hint**:

> October 11 1884

Comment: Your hint was quite an outrageous one. You basically gave away the answer. Without that, it was a really good puzzle.

Comment: @Anachor darn character limit made me do it. I couldn't think of anything else to put.

Comment: I can guarantee you, when most people see a riddle, first of all they read the hint, and if that hint is a date, the first thing they do is google it.

Comment: @Anachor can confirm, that's exactly what I did

Comment: @2xedo I know, I am speaking from "personal experience".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Eleanor Roosevelt

First part:

> "L" in "or" = Eleanor

Second part:

> Rows of "elt" = Roosevelt

Comment: Beat me to it smh